# fetching details of user having same reporting email address using join or alias

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, mysqli

I have two tables

tbl_user:

```
id fisrtname lastname
5   John      Doe
6   Peter     Parker
7   Will      Smith
```

tbl_experience:

```
exp_id usr_id user_reporting_to
1       5     dev@abc.com 
2       6     admin@abc.com
3       7     dev@abc.com
```

I want to fetch those record who have same reporting email address with where condition usr_id=5 because when i am login in to my page it creates the session of user id for e.g it is now 5 in where condition using join or alias

```
SELECT texperience.tbl_experience_report_to_email AS tbl_experience_report_to_email, 
    tuser.tbl_user_fname AS tbl_user_fname, 
    texperience.tbl_experience_designation AS tbl_experience_designation 
FROM tbl_experience AS texperience,
    tbl_user AS tuser 
WHERE tuser.tbl_user_fname = tuser.tbl_experience_id 
    AND texperience.tbl_experience_report_to_email = texperience.tbl_experience_id
    AND texperience.tbl_experience_user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT tbl_user.*, tbl_experience.user_reporting_to FROM tbl_user 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_experience ON (tbl_user.id=tbl_experience.usr_id) 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(*) as total_user, user_reporting_to FROM tbl_experience GROUP BY user_reporting_to) as email_group ON 
(email_group.user_reporting_to = tbl_experience.user_reporting_to) WHERE email_group.total_user > 1
```

Basically have a subquery that group all the email address and the joined table will return those users that have emails appearing more than once in the tbl_experience.